# Probability of mutually Independent events

Tags: probability

I'm a bit confused on how to solve this problem.

> Suppose the probability of dying in a skydiving accident is $0.04\%$ per jump, mutually independent with all other jumps.
>
> What is the largest integer $k$ such that the probability of surviving $k$ jumps is at least $99\%$?

So we know that probability of surviving is 99.96%. Since the jumps are mutually independent, would the answer be $.9996^k\geq .99$? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes you are right. Since events are independent, they simply multiply leading to this relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You’re absolutely on the right track. Two events are independent if
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$. In other words, the probability of them both occurring is the probability of the first event occurring multiplied by the probability of the second occurring.

Because of this, we know that the probability of surviving and then surviving again ($P(A\cap B)$) is just the product of their probabilities since the events are given to be mutually independent. So as you correctly observed, $.9996^2$. But then the probability of surviving again after this is the previous result multiplied by $.9996$. This continues for a total of $k$ steps until the result is less than $.99$.